# Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document)

Tags: xml, http, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, multipartform-data

Having this kind of error:

```
    Message               : "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException - Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
```

Input:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE infringement_upload_file PUBLIC "-//OSR//DTD Infringement Upload File//EN" "InfringementUploadFile.dtd">
<infringement_upload_file create_date="2012-03-26T17:30:07" device_controller_id="1234567">
   <infringement_list count="1">
      <infringement>
         <field name="infringement_number" value="11111" />
         <field name="type" value="8" />
         <field name="issue_date" value="23032012" />
      </infringement>
   </infringement_list>
</infringement_upload_file>
```

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::module::Multipart    
input payload application/xml
output multipart/form-data boundary="--------------------------abc123"
---
{
  "parts": {
    "credentials": {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": {
          "name": "credentials",
          "subtype": "form-data"
        }
      },
      "content": payload.parts.credentials.content as Binary {base: "64"}
    },
    "files": {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": {
          "name": "file",
          "filename": "100969_8.xml",
          "subtype": "form-data"
        },
        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
      },
      "content": payload.parts.files.content
  
      }
   }
}
```

What seems to be the problem? I have their sample test data. I'm doing a multipart http call.

Trying to send this multipart payload to an HTTP Request.